# How to access POST parameters into python web server using web.py module?

Tags: php, python, web.py, post-parameter

I write a python script like this:

```
import web
import commands

urls = ('getprint', 'GetPrint', 'postprint', 'PostPrint')

app = web.application(urls, globals())

class GetPrint:
  def GET(self):
    return "Hello, this is GetPrint function :D"

class PostPrint:
  def POST(self):
     # I don't know how to access to post data!!!
if __name__ == "__main__": app.run()
```

I want to use this script as a web service and call It via a php script from another machine. My php script to call the python web service is like this:

```
<?php ...
    require('CallRest.inc.php');
    ...
    $status = CallAPI('GET', "http://WEBSERVICE_MACHINE_IP:PORT/".$arg);
    echo $status;
    ...
    $data = array("textbox1" => $_POST["textbox1"]);
    CallAPI('POST', 'http://WEBSERVICE_MACHINE_IP:PORT/'.$arg, $data);
... ?>
```

And the header file 'CallRest.inc.php' is:

```
<?php
// Method: POST, PUT, GET etc
// Data: array("param" => "value") ==> index.php?param=value
function CallAPI($method, $url, $data = false)
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    switch ($method)
    {
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            if ($data)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            break;
        case "PUT":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
            break;
        default:
            if ($data)
                $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
    }
    // Optional Authentication:
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $result;
}       
?>
```

The class `GetPrint` work correctly but I don't know how to pass the post parameters to the python web service and how to access them into class `PostPrint`.

Comment: May be `request.params` is what you are looking for. Print this in your `post method`. It would print a MultiDict.

Comment: @uri2x, thanks so much. I used web.input(). This method returns a `Storage` class and I can access my POST data as a dictionary. My script is completed :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access POST data on your Python code you should define right after your `def POST(self)` a variable such as `data = web.input()`. Then you can access the fields as shown [here](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/tutorial), For example: `data.param1`, `data.name`, and so on. So your code should look as follows:

```
class PostPrint:
  def POST(self):
     data = web.input()

     param1 = data.param1
     name = data.name
     ...
```